# Adding Capital Markets Framework Bundles to apama_project

Tags: apama

The official documentation states that 'Adding bundles from the Capital Markets Foundation, Capital Markets Adapters, or user-defined bundle catalogs is not supported.'.

After inspecting how the officially supported bundles are added to the `.dependencies` file, however, I managed to successfully add a Capital Markets Bundle by providing a relative path from the product catalog as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<apama-project>
    <dependency>
        <dependencyentry path="" kind="src"/>
    </dependency>
    <catalogs>
    </catalogs>
    <bundles>
        <bundle file="DummyMDA.bnd" origin-path="../../../ApamaCapitalMarketsFoundation/ASB/bundles" origin="PRODUCT_CATALOG">
...
        </bundle>
    </bundles>
</apama-project>
```

I was able to `engine_deploy` this project without any issues and confirmed the dependency was injected when running `correlator --config /path/to/deploy/`.

Whilst not officially supported - is there any consequence to this approach? The `engine_deploy` and `apama_project` look to be able to replace a substantial chunk of `aunit test framework` bundling code using ant which would be favourable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer directly, I am fairly sure that there won't be a major issue with what you are doing here. It is a bit Hacky but the mechanism should handle it fine (as you have found). I will experiment a little and update here if there are issues.

Additionally It is interesting that you have actually done this now as we are currently working on providing a more comprehensive testing framework (unsure of exact targeted version) which might well help you further. I would be interested in gaining some insight into what you are doing and how we might make your life easier please message me if you would be interested in telling me more.

Comment: Thanks @Caribou. I appreciate the confirmation. Will PM you regarding testing framework.